# RangeSlider using combination of HTML, CSS and JS not working in Squarespace

Tags: javascript, squarespace, rangeslider

I have a code for a dynamic range slider which works on other sites but not on Squarespace. I am using the theme, Merida and the page can be found [here](http://dory-penguin-hfhg.squarespace.com/movie-guide/luxurious-ease-8gk6e-andwy). The code is meant to show the values in a teardrop shaped bubble which moves with the slider.

the full code is below, just incase i am wrong and it isn't the javascript that is faulty. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
html,body{
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  place-items: center;
  background: #664AFF;
}
.range{
  height: 80px;
  width: 380px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0 65px 0 45px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.sliderValue{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.sliderValue span{
  position: absolute;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  transform: translateX(-70%) scale(0);
  font-weight: 500;
  top: -40px;
  line-height: 55px;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.sliderValue span.show{
  transform: translateX(-70%) scale(1);
}
.sliderValue span:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #664AFF;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}
.field{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.field .value{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #664AFF;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.field .value.left{
  left: -22px;
}
.field .value.right{
  right: -43px;
}
.range input{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  z-index: 2222;
}
.range input::-webkit-slider-thumb{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #664AFF;
  border: 1px solid #664AFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.range input::-moz-range-thumb{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #664AFF;
  border: 1px solid #664AFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.range input::-moz-range-progress{
  background: #664AFF; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created By CodingNepal -->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="range">
        <div class="sliderValue">
          <span>100</span>
        </div>
<div class="field">
          <div class="value left">
0</div>
<input type="range" min="10" max="200" value="100" steps="1">
          <div class="value right">
200</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
      const slideValue = document.querySelector("span");
      const inputSlider = document.querySelector("input");
      inputSlider.oninput = (()=>{
        let value = inputSlider.value;
        slideValue.textContent = value;
        slideValue.style.left = (value/2) + "%";
        slideValue.classList.add("show");
      });
      inputSlider.onblur = (()=>{
        slideValue.classList.remove("show");
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, you'll want to provide the view-only password for the site. Because it is in trial-mode, it has a temporary, view-only password that others will need to view the site. Secondly, assuming that you're adding at least some of the code via a code block, then you will not want to include some of the HTML which your code includes, such as `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` elements. Thirdly, the JavaScript, as written, will assumes there is only one `span` and one `input` on the page. If there are others (and there likely are) the code will not work as desired.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. How do i solve the javascript assumption. I believe there is more than one span.